# Media Server not showing on public Wi-Fi

Tags: wireless-networking, video-streaming

I live in an apartment complex. Recently, the administration switched to Wi-Fi (probably to save on costs) as opposed to wired Internet. Before, I had my own router and I could stream videos to my Blu-ray player ([Sony S3500](http://www.sony.com/electronics/blu-ray-disc-players/bdp-s3500)) via Windows Media Server and [Serviio](http://serviio.org) in Windows 10.

Now, being on that public Wi-Fi that I join with a password, I don’t see my media servers or any other peoples’ servers. Is there any way I can see my media servers on this public Wi-Fi?

P.S. I already tried creating a hotspot via the [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me) application, but it was terribly unstable, losing connection all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not. Public Wi-Fi networks are often configured to do "client isolation", which makes it act like separate Internet connections for each device rather than act as a shared LAN. Multicasts and broadcasts between clients are blocked, which blocks service discovery protocols.

Answer (score 1):

How about attaching a wireless to ethernet bridge to a router that is on a different subnet?

check your ip address and notate(say it is 192.168.1.11)

Add a wireless ethernet bridge(converts wireless to ethernet)

Plug that into another router on a different subnet(say 10.0.0.1)

Make sure router is on different channel the main wireless, or even  different frequency(5 ghz?)

Connect your devices to router, and thats it!